# mongoose how to $match the attribute '_id' of an object with all the results of an array in another object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm making an API in NodeJS using mongoose, and I have to models that I need to relate:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({{...}

  favs: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Propuesta'
  }]
}, {...}
})
```

and an object called 'Propuesta', which has his own id

What I need is in the controller, use the $match operator to get all the id's of the model Propuesta that are include in the array 'favs', and then use $group to get the most repeated Partido (which is another model and this functionality works fine).

Obviously, 'favs' is an array that grows dynamically, so for what I've seen, I need to use the operator $or inside the code of $match, but I don't know how to write the syntax to say "if this id is equals favs[0], OR favs[1], OR favs[n]"

This is my method by now (I know that right now is comparing if my id is equal to the whole String "[id:{...},id:{...}...]"

```
export const partidoAfin = ({ user, querymen: { query, select, cursor } }, res, next) => {


  Propuesta
  .aggregate([
    {
      '$match': {
         $or: {'_id': user.favs}
      }
    },
      {'$group': {
            '_id': '$partido',
            'partidoCount': {'$sum': 1}
          }},
          {'$sort': {partidoCount: -1}}
        ])
        .then(success(res))
        .catch(next)
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you provide some dummy documents.  If possible the desired result also. So I can execute it in my local system.

Comment: you can download the project with all the documents in mlab, the folder is api:  https://github.com/JoseAlbertoVazq/tuvotocuenta   thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide some documents structure of Propuesta collection. Its better

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
export const partidoAfin = ({ user, querymen: { query } }, res, next) => {

  let arrayIds = []
  arrayIds = user.favs

    Propuesta
    .aggregate([
      {
        '$match': {
           '_id': {'$in': arrayIds}
        }
      },
        {'$group': {
              '_id': '$partido',
              'partidoCount': {'$sum': 1}
            }},
            {'$sort': {partidoCount: -1}}
          ]).then((result) => ({
            count: result.length,
            rows: result
          }))
          .then(success(res))
          .catch(next)
}
```